# How to run an Electron application as a service in windows?

Tags: electron

I have created an Electron application and now I want to run this application as window service. I try to search for it and ended up with a npm called "npm install os-service", I tried to install it but shows an error. I want to know that is there any other way to achieve my goal? Does anyone have any solution for this?

Comment: You are aware I hope that Windows services cannot interact with the desktop in any way, so one must wonder why did you choose Electron for such a task.

Comment: Thank you so much for you reply @Remus Rusanu